# Function running again when I set a variable with it

Tags: python

```
import random
import os
done = []
def process():
  a = []
  for i in range (len(info)):
    ans = str(input(info[i][0]))
    os.system("clear")
    if info[i][1] == True:
      ans = ans.capitalize()
    a.append(ans)
  return a
numlibs = 1
for i in range (numlibs):
  num = random.randint(1, numlibs)
  
  if num == 1 and 1 not in done:
    info = [["COLOR: ", False], ["COLOR: ", False], ["EXCLAMATION: ", True]]
    process()
    a = process()
    print(len(info))
    print("My pizza is " + a[0] + " and my tater tots are " + a[1] + "! " + a[2] + "!")
    done.append(1)
```

I used the debug mode in Replit to see when the function is running, and it runs both when I call the function and when I set variable "a" near the end. Why does this happen and how do I fix it?

Comment: You call the function twice in two lines, the second time the result is assigned to `a`, were you not expecting `a = process()` to run the function?

Comment: `a = process()` calls the function and assigns the returned result to `a` - the call to `process()` before it is unneeded. The result just gets discarded after the first call. (also, do yourself and everyone that has to work with you a favour, and use standard size 4 indentation, instead of 2)

Comment: You speaking of fixing, so you see an errror. What error are you seeing?